# Узнать, использует ли процесс ASLR и DEP C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

Часть данного вопроса уже обсуждалась на форуме, но в данный момент задача стоит немного иная. Нужно получить информацию о том, использует ли процесс технологии ASLR и DEP на языке C#.

Данный код, являющийся реинтерпретацией [этого кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573836/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8E-aslr-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c), работает верно:

```
    /* Definitions required for getting policies */
    const int Process_Query_Information = 0x0400;
    const int Process_WM_Read = 0x0010;

    public enum Process_Mitigation_Policy
    {
        ProcessDEPPolicy = 0,
        ProcessASLRPolicy = 1
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct union
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        uint EnableBottomUpRandomization;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        uint EnableForceRelocateImages;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        uint EnableHighEntropy;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        uint DisallowStrippedImages;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        uint ReservedFlags;
    }

    public struct Process_Mitigation_Type_Policy
    {
        uint Flags;

        bool EnableBottomUpRandomization
        {
            get { return (Flags & 1) > 0; }
        }

        bool EnableForceRelocateImage
        {
            get { return (Flags & 2) > 0; }
        }

        bool EnableHighEntropy
        {
            get { return (Flags & 4) > 0; }
        }

        bool DisallowStrippedImages
        {
            get { return (Flags & 8) > 0; }
        }
    }
```

По аналогии я пытался получить информацию о DEP. [Согласно MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769087(v=vs.85).aspx), определил структуру такого типа:

```
    public struct Process_Mitigation_DEP_Policy
    {
        uint Flags;

        bool Enable
        {
            get { return (Flags & 1) > 0; }
        }

        bool DisableAtlThunkEmulation
        {
            get { return (Flags & 2) > 0; }
        }
    }
```

Попробовав использовать реализованный функционал, выяснилось, что с данной структурой те же самые функции работать отказываются. Одна из проблем - мне нужно определить union другого вида, опять же, согласно MSDN ([union для DEP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769087(v=vs.85).aspx)), но тогда возникает ошибка переопределения union. Как определить другую структуру и использовать её в том же коде верно мне неясно, особенно учитывая то, что функции WINAPI, описанные на MSDN, представляют примеры функций для C++ и перенос последних на C# тоже достаточно затруднителен.

Вопрос: как правильно получить информацию об использовании DEP и ASLR процессом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли поле `Permanent` в структуре:

```
struct Process_Mitigation_DEP_Policy
{
    uint Flags;
    bool Permanent;

    bool Enable
    {
        get { return (Flags & 1) > 0; }
    }

    bool DisableAtlThunkEmulation
    {
        get { return (Flags & 2) > 0; }
    }
}
```

Далее, действительно, функция `GetProcessMitigationPolicy` принимает 3-м аргументом указатель на одну из множества структур. Поэтому необходимо объявить соответствующие перегрузки, для всех типов структур, которые вы собираетесь использовать:

```
// Для ASLR
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetProcessMitigationPolicy(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY mitigationPolicy,
    ref Process_Mitigation_DEP_Policy lpBuffer,
    int dwLength);

// Для DEP
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetProcessMitigationPolicy(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY mitigationPolicy,
    ref PROCESS_MITIGATION_ASLR_POLICY lpBuffer,
    int dwLength);
```

Функцию вызываем как раньше, передавая ей соответствующую структуру:

```
// информация по DEP
var depPolicy = new Process_Mitigation_DEP_Policy();

bool success = GetProcessMitigationPolicy(hProc,
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY.ProcessDEPPolicy,
    ref depPolicy, Marshal.SizeOf(depPolicy));

if (success) {
    // ...
}

// информация по ASLR
var aslrPolicy = new PROCESS_MITIGATION_ASLR_POLICY();

success = GetProcessMitigationPolicy(hProc,
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY.ProcessASLRPolicy,
    ref aslrPolicy, Marshal.SizeOf(aslrPolicy));

if (success) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, ваш ответ действительно помог - код выполняется верно. Единственный момент - не могу получить информацию о DEP о 64-битных приложениях (функция возвращает false, в то время как Process Explorer говорит, что DEP для данного приложения включен, а наблюдается это только в случае 64-битных приложений), с 32-битными всё работает. Не подскажете, как решить данную ситуацию? Возможно, решить можно через WMI? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Извините, @kmv , забыл указать ваш ник в комментарии

Comment: @BrianO'Conner действительно, для 64-битных процессов не работает. Не могу пока сказать, почему.

Comment: @BrianO'Conner возможно потому, что для 64-битрых процессов DEP включен всегда и отключить его нельзя: On 64-bit versions of Windows, if hardware-enforced DEP is available it is always applied to 64-bit processes and kernel memory spaces and there are no system configuration settings to disable it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209052/iis-how-to-disable-data-execution-prevention-in-windows-server-2008

Comment: Спасибо большое, @kmv , учту это в программе